# Mule: after delivering a message, save the current timestamp for later use. What's the correct idiom?

Tags: persistence, mule

I'm connecting to a third-party web service to retrieve rows from the underlying database. I can optionally pass a parameter like this:

```
http://server.com/resource?createdAfter=[yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss]
```

to get only the rows created after a given date.

This means I have to store the current timestamp (using #[function:datestamp:...], no problem) in one message scope and then retrieve it in another.

It also implies the timestamp should be preserved in case of an outage.

Obviously, I could use a subflow containing a file endpoint, saving in a designated file on a path. But, intuitively, based on my (very!) limited experience, it feels hackish.

What's the correct idiom to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object Store Module is designed just for that: to allow you to save bits of information from your flows.

See:

- http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/mule/objectstore-config.html
- https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-objectstore/

Comment: Is there a Mule question you can't answer, David? Many thanks!